# How to handle \footnote command in example environment made using tcolorbox package?

Tags: environments, footnotes, tcolorbox

I want to use the example environment that was suggested by @Jonathan in the related [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21227/example-environment). This is almost the same MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{testexample}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\exampletext{Example}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{testexample}{ O{} }
{
\colorlet{colexam}{red!55!black}
\newtcolorbox[use counter=testexample]{testexamplebox}{
    empty,
    title={\exampletext: #1},
    attach boxed title to top left,
       minipage boxed title,
    boxed title style={empty,size=minimal,toprule=0pt,top=4pt,left=3mm,overlay={}},
coltitle=colexam,fonttitle=\bfseries,
before=\par\medskip\noindent,parbox=false,boxsep=0pt,left=3mm,right=0mm,top=2pt,breakable,pad at break=0mm,
   before upper=\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname0pt,
overlay unbroken={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
overlay first={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
overlay middle={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
overlay last={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },%
}
\begin{testexamplebox}}
{\end{testexamplebox}\endlist}

\begin{document}

\begin{testexample}[Latin Text]
\lipsum[1]\footnote{my footnote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{testexample}

\end{document}
```

Then, I want that `\footnote` made footnote at the bottom of the page not in the end of the example. I have already found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263693/footnote-in-a-tcolorbox-environment) on the similar question but it was about using already appeared earlier footnotes. Can I do the same when `\footnote` only appears once in the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way be redefining footnote inside your environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{testexample}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{FootnoteCounter}
\newcounter{Init}
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\def\exampletext{Example}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{testexample}{ O{} }
{
\colorlet{colexam}{red!55!black}
\newtcolorbox[use counter=testexample]{testexamplebox}{
    empty,
    title={\exampletext: #1},
    attach boxed title to top left,
       minipage boxed title,
    boxed title style={empty,size=minimal,toprule=0pt,top=4pt,left=3mm,overlay={}},
coltitle=colexam,fonttitle=\bfseries,
before=\par\medskip\noindent,parbox=false,boxsep=0pt,left=3mm,right=0mm,top=2pt,breakable,pad at break=0mm,
   before upper=\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname0pt,
overlay unbroken={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
overlay first={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
overlay middle={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
overlay last={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },%
}
\begin{testexamplebox}%
\setcounter{Init}{\value{footnote}}
\setcounter{FootnoteCounter}{\value{Init}}
\def\footnote##1{\stepcounter{footnote}\stepcounter{FootnoteCounter}\footnotemark[\arabic{FootnoteCounter}]\def\temp{##1}\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname F\arabic{FootnoteCounter}\endcsname\temp
}}
{\end{testexamplebox}\endlist\stepcounter{Init}\foreach \f in {\arabic{Init},...,\arabic{FootnoteCounter}}{\footnotetext[\f]{\csname F\f\endcsname}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{testexample}[Latin Text]
\lipsum[1]\footnote{my first footnote}
\lipsum[2]\footnote{Another Footnote}
\end{testexample}

A text with a footnote here\footnote{Test Outside}

\begin{testexample}[Latin Text]
\lipsum[1]\footnote{my third footnote}
\lipsum[2]\footnote{Another Footnote}
\end{testexample}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great example, +1 for multiple footnotes and boxed.  Are `xparse` and `pgffor` actually used in your example?

Comment: You define a counter, but don't use it.  It might be useful to rename it to e.g. `examplecnt` and use it as e.g. `title={Example~\arabic{examplecnt}: #1},`.

Comment: Thanks @AstroFloyd ... Actually if you see the OPs question this is his/her code changed ... I didn't changed the original code so that the OP can use it directly in his example and not just in this MWE

Comment: `pgffor` is used in the `\foreach` loop ... Could be avoided by a TeX loop or alternatives.

Comment: Thanks!  I have another question.  As soon as I remove all footnotes from one of the boxes, I get empty footnote markers at the bottom of the page.  This only seems to work correctly if there is at least one footnote in each box.  Is there a way to circumvent this, so that the Example environment can be used both with and without footnotes?